# How to check if words start with a hashtag in a Label then do something

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a label that contains up to 255 characters. In that label users can write words including words with hashtags such as :"This is an image at the hotel in #Thailand". Now I want #Thailand to be displayed as a link. Is there a simple and straight forward way to check the words that start with hashtags? Here is a sample of what I would like to accomplish.

```
Label photoCaptionLabel = FindControl("photoCaptionLabel") as Label;
string photoCaptionLabelText = photoCaptionLabel.Text;

string[] split = photoCaptionLabelText.Split();

foreach (string s in split)
{
// if the word starts with hashtag turn it into a link    }
...
```

Comment: `if (s.IndexOf('#') == 0`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
if(s.StartsWith("#"))
```

Alternatively you can also check for the first char:

```
if(s[0] == '#')
```

This is prone to error is `s` is an empty string.You can use [`RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option in your `Split` method to avoid this.

Comment: Great... and now how can I assign a new string to s? The word that contains a hashtag (#Thailand) should become a link as follows "htPage.aspx?ht=#Thailand"

Comment: @Gloria you wanna change the `photoCaptionLabel.Text` by using `Replace` method. `photoCaptionLabel.Text = photoCaptionLabel.Text.Replace(s, "new value"));`

Comment: Thanks for the help. For performance purposes, is it better to replace and save the hashtags as links in the database or to replace the hashtags with links from code behind when the text is rendered on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote function to do it, just pass photo caption label text to it:

```
private static string HashTag(string photoCaptionLabelText)
{
    //Regular expression to find hash tag with word after hash w+ and put it to 2 grouping
    //1 grouping will be hash #
    string replacePattern = @"(#)(\w+)";

    //replacement string will replace #Thailand matched by our pattern with htPage.aspx?ht=#Thailand
    //$2 is back reference that will carry word after hash tag to your link
    //you can make it a function to generate your custom links and where you will put $2 you will get word from hash tag
    string replacementString = @"htPage.aspx?ht=#$2";

    //Actual replacement
    return Regex.Replace(inputText, replacePattern, replacementString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split with regex, so it would work no matter what whitespace characters (and how many of them) user entered, and you could use LINQ .Where method to make it nicer, cleaner and in one line ;)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var text = "test1 test2 test3 #tag1 #tag2 #tag3";
            var tags = Regex.Split(text, @"\s+").Where(i => i.StartsWith("#"));
            Debug.Print("TAGS: " + String.Join(", ", tags));
        }
    }
}
```